# pyspark - how to filter again based on a filter result by window function

Tags: pyspark

I have below dataframe which contains 4 columns: timestamp, firstID, secondID and type. The type column has 3 values: type1,type2 and type3

```
timestamp,firstID,secondID,type
"2022-12-05 05:04:09,049",fisrtID1,secondID1,type1
"2022-12-05 05:05:09,049",firstID1,secondID1,type2
"2022-12-05 05:06:09,049",firstID1,secondID1,type3
"2022-12-06 05:04:09,049",firstID2,secondID2,type1
"2022-12-07 05:04:09,049",firstID3,firstID3,type2
"2022-12-07 05:07:09,049",firstID3,firstID3,type3
"2022-12-07 05:04:09,049",firstID4,firstID4,type1
"2022-12-07 05:07:09,049",firstID4,firstID4,type3
...
```

Expected result to return  :

1. when the partitioned window group contains records for both type1, type2 and type3, then return the record with type3.
2. when the partitioned window group contains records for both type1 and type2,
   then return the record with type2
3. when the partitioned window group contains records for both type1 and type2,
   then return the record with type3
   4.when the partitioned window group contains only 1 record(no matter type1 or type2 or types),
   then just return that record.

here is the sample output:

```
timestamp,firstID,secondID,type
"2022-12-05 05:06:09,049",firstID1,secondID1,type3
"2022-12-06 05:04:09,049",firstID2,secondID2,type1
"2022-12-07 05:07:09,049",firstID3,firstID3,type3
"2022-12-07 05:07:09,049",firstID4,firstID4,type3
```

The code I am trying, but I don't know how to correctly continue for getting the expected result.

```
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("firstID","secondID").orderBy(col("timestamp").desc())
```

Can anyone please help advice?

Comment: expected output sample?

Comment: add expected output in description

Comment: can you add your current code? how you use this window ?

Comment: actully, i don't know how to check the condition based on each partition widnow. how should i refer to each partition window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve in 1 window function and when-otherwise condition:

```
df_2 = df.withColumn(
    'type_collection', func.collect_set('type').over(Window.partitionBy('first_id', 'second_id').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing))
).withColumn(
    'is_deleted', func.when(func.array_contains('type_collection', 'type3')&(func.col('type')=='type3'), func.lit(False))
                      .when((~func.array_contains('type_collection', 'type3'))&(func.array_contains('type_collection', 'type2'))&(func.col('type')=='type2'), func.lit(False))
                      .when(func.size(func.col('type_collection'))==1, func.lit(False))
                      .otherwise(func.lit(True))
).filter(
    func.col('is_deleted') == False
).select(
    'timestamp', 'first_id', 'second_id', 'type'
)

df_2.show(10, False)
+-----------------------+--------+---------+-----+
|timestamp              |first_id|second_id|type |
+-----------------------+--------+---------+-----+
|2022-12-05 05:06:09,049|firstID1|secondID1|type3|
|2022-12-06 05:04:09,049|firstID2|secondID2|type1|
|2022-12-07 05:07:09,049|firstID3|firstID3 |type3|
|2022-12-07 05:07:09,049|firstID4|firstID4 |type3|
+-----------------------+--------+---------+-----+
```

Step1: Collect the `type` as a set within the partition.

Step2: Setup the condition based on your expected result.

Step3: Filter the unless row.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question. For simplicity I have shown step by step. However, you have given no condition where more than one scenario exists. For instance, where `type1,type2,type3` and `type1,type2` occur in the same partition which one gets picked over the other. That situation arises in `firstID1`

#Create a filter data frame

```
d =spark.createDataFrame([('type1,type2,type3', 'type3'),
                         ('type1,type2', 'type2'),
                          ('type2,type3', 'type3'),
                          ('type1,type3', 'type3'),
                         ('type1','type1'),
                         ('type2','type2')],
                        ('cond', 'type'))


new = (df.withColumn('filter1', (sort_array(collect_set('type').over(Window.partitionBy('firstID')))))# create a list column from which to extract filters
         .withColumn('filter', array_join('filter1',','))#filter condition 1
        .withColumn('filter1', size('filter1')) #filter condition 2
         
       .join(broadcast(d),on='type',how='left')#Use broadcast join to avoid shuffle to append filter conftion df to the main
       .withColumn('filter3', size(split(col('cond'),'\,')))#Create filter 3
         #Apply filter conditions
       .where( (col('filter3')>1)&(col('filter1')>1)&(col('filter').contains(col('cond')))) or (col('filter1')==1)&(col('filter')==col('cond'))
       
      ).drop('filter','filter1', 'filter3').show(truncate=False)

+-----+-----------------------+--------+---------+
|type |timestamp              |firstID |secondID |
+-----+-----------------------+--------+---------+
|type2|2022-12-05 05:05:09,049|firstID1|secondID1|
|type3|2022-12-05 05:06:09,049|firstID1|secondID1|
|type3|2022-12-05 05:06:09,049|firstID1|secondID1|
|type3|2022-12-07 05:07:09,049|firstID3|firstID3 |
|type3|2022-12-07 05:07:09,049|firstID4|firstID4 |
+-----+-----------------------+--------+---------+
```